# How to label xaxis by dates in dataframe in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble figuring out how to label the x axis to correspond to points. X represent 4 dates and I would like the month-day (e.g., 'Aug 27') format to appear as x labels.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Code:

```
ggplot(day28.long,aes(x=day,y=movement))+
 geom_point(aes(colour=Horse))+
  geom_line(aes(colour=Horse))
```

The structure of the data is:

```
str(day28.long)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ day     : Date, format: "2016-08-27" "2016-09-24" "2016-10-22" "2016-11-19" ...
 $ Horse   : chr  "42012" "42012" "42012" "42012" ...
 $ movement: int  418 291 255 123 314 270 271 141 444 471 ...
```

[image: Plot where x labels aren't matched to points]

Comment: Your plot already appears to have the `Mon-Day` format. What is it you are looking to change? Also, please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to provide a reproducible example. In the mean time, look into `scale_x_date` and if that doesn't work for what you want, explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `ggplot2` uses `scale_x_date()` or `scale_y_date()`, resp., for class `Date` axes. Tick marks and grid lines are placed at "nice" dates, e.g., 1<sup>st</sup> and 15<sup>th</sup> of a month. Scaling doesn't care about specific dates in the data.

However, `scale_*_date()` has two parameters which allow to customize breaks and labels.

```
ggplot(day28.long,aes(x=day, y=movement, colour=Horse, group = Horse)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(day28.long$day),
               date_labels = "%b %d"
  )
```

[image]

The `breaks` are taken from the `day` column.

By default, labels would appear in the `YYYY-mm-dd` format. Therefore, the parameter `date_labels = "%b %d"` tells `ggplot2` how to display the dates on the axis.

Note that `%b` is the *Abbreviated month name in the **current locale** on this platform* (see `?strptime`). This is why *Okt 22* is printed in the chart instead of *Oct 22*.

### Data

Unfortunately, the OP hasn't provided the data for a reproducible example. So, I had to make some sample data.

```
day28.long <- data.frame(
  day = as.Date(rep(c("2016-08-27", "2016-09-24", "2016-10-22", "2016-11-19"), 2)),
  Horse = rep(c("42012", "42013"), each = 4),
  movement = as.integer(c(418, 291, 255, 123, 314, 270, 271, 141)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(day28.long)
#'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ day     : Date, format: "2016-08-27" "2016-09-24" "2016-10-22" ...
# $ Horse   : chr  "42012" "42012" "42012" "42012" ...
# $ movement: int  418 291 255 123 314 270 271 141
```

Comment: Any idea how to use a different locale other than temporarily setting one with `Sys.setlocale()`?